# JQuery SetBubblePopup

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I have a weird error

I wrote this code against  setbubblepopup

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').hover(function () {

```
        var tempID = $(this).attr("id");
        var tempTitle = $(this).attr("title");
        var totalID = ("'a#") + tempID + ("'");

        console.log(totalID);

       $(totalID).SetBubblePopup({
            innerHtml: tempTitle
        });



    });

});
```

when I run it I get Selector expected.
The console log show me 'a#thirdlink' so I am getting the correct format

When I put:

```
$('a#thirdlink').SetBubblePopup({
            innerHtml: tempTitle
        });
```

it works with no errors that's what is weird.
When I use my var totalID it doesn't work and when I hard code it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding an extra set of quotes in there, this:

```
var totalID = ("'a#") + tempID + ("'");
```

Should just be:

```
var totalID = "a#" + tempID;
```

This isn't a valid selector: `$("'a#something'")`, but this is: `$("a#something")` :)

Overall though, an ID should be unique in the page, you can just use `$(this)` instead of constructing a selector...if your IDs are unique, `this` already refers to the element you want, so this should work:

```
$(this).SetBubblePopup({ innerHtml: tempTitle });
```